# Re-execute async RxJS stream after delay

Tags: rxjs

I'm using RxJS 6 to lazily step through iterable objects using code similar to example running below. This is working well but I'm having trouble solving my final use case.

Full code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-h3gdcf)

```js
import { EMPTY, defer, from, of } from "rxjs";
import { delay, expand, mergeMap, repeat } from "rxjs/operators";

function stepIterator (iterator) {
  return defer(() => of(iterator.next())).pipe(
    mergeMap(result => result.done ? EMPTY : of(result.value))
  );
}

function iterateValues ({ params }) {
  const { values, delay: delayMilliseconds } = params;
  const isIterable = typeof values[Symbol.iterator] === "function";

  // Iterable values which are emitted over time are handled manually. Otherwise
  // the values are provided to Rx for resolution.
  if (isIterable && delayMilliseconds > 0) {
    const iterator = values[Symbol.iterator]();

    // The first value is emitted immediately, the rest are emitted after time.
    return stepIterator(iterator).pipe(
      expand(v => stepIterator(iterator).pipe(delay(delayMilliseconds)))
    );
  } else {
    return from(values);
  }
}

const options = { 
  params: {
    // Any iterable object is walked manually. Otherwise delegate to `from()`.
    values: ["Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"],
    // Delay _between_ values.
    delay: 350,
    // Delay before the stream restarts _after the last value_.
    runAgainAfter: 1000,
  }
};

iterateValues(options)
  // Is not repeating?!
  .pipe(repeat(3))
  .subscribe(
    v => {
      console.log(v, Date.now());
    },
    console.error,
    () => {
      console.log('Complete');
    }
  );
```

I'd like to add in another option which will re-execute the stream, an indefinite number of times, after a delay (`runAgainAfter`). I'm having trouble composing this in cleanly without factoring the `result.done` case deeper. So far I've been unable to compose the run-again behavior around `iterateValues`.

What's the best approach to accomplish the use case?

Thanks!

Edit 1: `repeat` just hit me in the face. Perhaps it means to be friendly.
Edit 2: No, repeat isn't repeating but the observable is completing. Thanks for any help. I'm confused.

---

For posterity here is the full code sample for a revised edition is `repeat`-able and uses a consistent delay between items.

```js
import { concat, EMPTY, defer, from, interval, of, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { delay, expand, mergeMap, repeat } from "rxjs/operators";

function stepIterator(iterator) {
  return defer(() => of(iterator.next())).pipe(
    mergeMap(result => (result.done ? EMPTY : of(result.value)))
  );
}

function iterateValues({ params }) {
  const { values, delay: delayMilliseconds, times = 1 } = params;
  const isIterable =
    values != null && typeof values[Symbol.iterator] === "function";

  if (!isIterable) {
    return throwError(new Error(`\`${values}\` is not iterable`));
  }

  // Iterable values which are emitted over time are handled manually. Otherwise
  // the values are provided to Rx for resolution.
  const observable =
    delayMilliseconds > 0
      ? defer(() => of(values[Symbol.iterator]())).pipe(
          mergeMap(iterator =>
            stepIterator(iterator).pipe(
              expand(v => stepIterator(iterator).pipe(delay(delayMilliseconds)))
            )
          )
        )
      : from(values);

  return observable.pipe(repeat(times));
}
```

Comment: I think you should just use `from` http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from you can pass an iterable to it and it'll convert it to an observable

Comment: also, do you really need an iterable here? as the `values` from `options` is not built in a lazy way? If you just want to emit en array with a given delay you can definitely do something simpler

Comment: I wasn't able to blend a delay in with `from` yielding. The iterable makes it easier to emit values from Set/Map/Array/String etc. You're super right that emitting values an index lookup is super easy.

I figured out the `repeat` isn't working because the `iterator` is created in the helper vs the `defer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna be honest, but there could be better solution for sure. In my solution, I ended up encapsulating delay logic in a custom `runAgainAfter` operator. Making it an independent part, that doesn't affect your code logic directly.

Full working code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ggqrtv?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

And the code of `runAgainAfter` if anybody needs it:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export const runAgainAfter = delay => observable => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    let timeout;
    let subscription;
    const subscribe = () => {
      return observable.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          observer.next(value);
        },
        error(err) {
          observer.error(err);
        },
        complete() {
          timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            subscription = subscribe();
          }, delay);
        }
      });
    };
    subscription = subscribe();

    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  });
};
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't successful before using an inner observable. Thanks a lot for the working code and turning up another approach to consider. :)

Comment: After fixing the `iterator` problem in my original sample (it was created in the factory not at subscribe time) then `repeat` worked. It offered a chance to clean up the interface too.

Instead of two delays this version has single delay and a number of times that the series should be emitted: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8njta4?embed=1&file=index.ts&hideExplorer=1. Thanks again. :)